# Rails 3 and delayed_job on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, delayed-job, vps, railscasts

Using delayed_job gem with my rails 3 app on development working great but when I tried to use it on production using capistrano it gives me these error

> script/delayed_job: Permission denied

I am using their method 
and I followed These Railscast video

http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Rails-3-and-Capistrano

Comment: I am not using root user I deploy with another user

Comment: What are the permissions on the file and who is the owner? Run `ls -l script/delayed_job` and post the output here... Also, with which user are you trying to run the command (`whoami`)?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x    1 remony    Administ      175 Jul  6 04:01 script/delayed_job

Comment: Ok. And you are trying to run the script as `remony`?

Comment: I am using widnows on my local machine ..and ubuntu on my vps

Comment: That shouldn't matter... As which user are you trying to run `script/delayed_job` on the VPS? Maybe it would also help if you post your complete output...

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything more (what users are you using? how do the permissions on the file look like?), I can't give you a better solution than to try

```
chmod a+x script/delayed_job
```

to give everyone execution permission for the `script/delayed_job` file...

Comment: I am using windows on my local machine and on VPS server I deploy with another user not root .Its not working